# CACHING : Spring Boot redis, remove expired records from cache

Tags: spring-boot, caching, redis

I am working on Movie-ticket-booking-system project, I have an API to get-upcoming-Booking-Details which are booked by the user,(it will show all booking details for user which are having showDateAndTime greater than current_time).
that API is frequently getting called as it I am show upcoming-Booked-shows in home screen,

1. For now I am looking to cache the response user wise, but problem is, I only want the showTimes greater than current_time , how will I be able to remove redundant records from the cache? -I cant use redis-expiry as we can only set it on key, I want key to be cachename_username, and intend to set expiry on internal fields.
2. Is it a good practice to cache data user-wise, I am not getting good feeling here?

Any suggestions are appreciated, thanks